# Command "serve" is not defined (Lumen-Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, lumen, lumen-5.2

So, i try to install the lumen restful api. Based on tutorial, i have to "serve" on php artisan. The command be like:

php artisan serve sample_api sample_api/public

then it shows:

[Command "serve" not defined.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWR1P.jpg)

Some say that serve command has been deleted in laravel 5 (which i use it). if so, what command should i use? or maybe find another tutorial?

Ps: Im a newbie :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 49):

You can use

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t public/
```

Comment: In windows, you can also make a .bat/.cmd with the command in the answer and name it like `serve.bat`, then you can run it from windows cmd. :)

Answer (score 3):

This command was removed from Lumen 5.2. You can use any other web server to run your app. I'd recommend to learn [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) with built-in environment. If you're newbie, you can use something like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/).

Comment: I can't believe how docs are outdated and there is no example how to run it on plain apache (must use virtual host). Damn.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no `artisan make:command` in Lumen, you can follow this procedure to reimplement `artisan serve`, or even use it as a template to create other console commands.

The serve command was removed since Laravel Lumen 5.2, but you can reimplement it manually as it follows:

Get the [ServeCommand.php file from Lumnen 5.0](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Console/Commands/ServeCommand.php), save it to the folder `app/Console/Commands` and perform these 2 tweaks:

1. Change the namespace from `Laravel\Lumen\Console\Commands` to `App\Console\Commands`.
2. Rename the function `fire` to `__invoke`.

Edit the file `app/Console/Kernel.php` to tell artisan the existence of this new command by listing it in the `$commands` member, like so:

```php
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\ServeCommand::class,
    ];
```

After doing that, you should be able to run `artisan serve`. Notice that [it will be serving a file `server.php`](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Console/Commands/ServeCommand.php#L39) from your project root folder. You need to create this file, or change the code to serve something else.

---